# Apache : How to upgrade apache 2.4.x version to latest 2.4.25

Tags: apache, apache2.4

How to upgrade apache2.4.9 to latest stable version apache2.4.25?

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu 12.04 is a Long Term Support release. This means that the version of Apache included with it will continue to receive security updates into 2017. So while you might not have the most recent version installed, security patches are backported to your version. So you shouldn't necessarily be concerned that you don't have the latest.

When making upgrades to a major piece of software like Apache, you risk making your system unstable. One of the main reasons for using a distribution's package management system rather than installing the latest upstream software is that you get a set of packages that have been tested together. If you update one outside of the package management system, you may introduce incompatibilities. This can particularly be a problem if you rely on non-default Apache modules.

If you really need a more recent version of Apache, I'd suggest upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04. If you don't want to do that, you can still get a more recent version by enabling this PPA:

```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
     sudo apt-get update
     sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Make sure you upgrade your configuration files as well, see [https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html]

Comment: Can we do by only updating /bin and /modules folder?

Comment: i hv updated the answer. and this alsohelp you.  
Adding this PPA to your system
You can update your system with unsupported packages from this untrusted PPA by adding ppa:ondrej/apache2 to your system's Software Sources.
To read about installing 
[https://launchpad.net/+help-soyuz/ppa-sources-list.html]

Comment: confused, who said anything about ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: How to update largely depends on how you installed it. Please elaborate on your question.